# Spring Security /login not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to create a simple REST API, I am using Angular 6 and Spring Boot. I wanted to implement logging to my app but whenever I try to sign up I get 404 Not Found /login. I have looked up to existing similar issues I found but nothing seems to help me.

Here's my spring security configuration ( I am sure that my sign up form and controller works properly, so I guess the issue lies somewhere down there)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


   @Value("${allowedOriginAddress}")
    private String allowedOriginAddress;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDataDetailsService userDataDetailsService() {
        return new UserDataDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(
                        Arrays.asList(
                                allowedOriginAddress,
                                allowedOriginAddress + "/*")
                        );
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","DELETE","OPTIONS","PUT"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureForwardUrl("/prev")
                .successForwardUrl("/next")
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDataDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class WhispererApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WhispererApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find the authentication configuration in your project. Please try adding the next code:

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

I think your code will be:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
}
```

The JWTAuthenticationFilter and JWTAuthorizationFilter are to manage the JWT if you are using that to authenticate the user.